# How to handle 24 hours clock across days using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Code to generate data using `tidyverse` v1.3.2:

```
submits <- tibble::tribble(
  ~ id, ~ submission, ~ day,
  1, "18:25:12", 2,
  2, "01:37:40", 3,
  3, "11:40:50", 2, 
  4, "00:55:00", 2
)
```

Data:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
     id submission   day
  <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>
1     1 18:25:12       2
2     2 01:37:40       3
3     3 11:40:50       2
4     4 00:55:00       2
```

The column `submission` denotes when `id` submitted a form using a 24 hr clock with reference to a particular date - we can assume the date information is not available to us. The column `day` denotes the days passed between the reference date and the submission date.

I wish to plot a scatter plot with `day` on x-axis and `submission` on y-axis for all submission (no grouping, duplicates from a particular `id` is allowed).

However, I have been unable to accomplish it with the following code:

```
submits %>%
  mutate(submission = as.POSIXct(submission, format = "%H:%M:%S")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x= day, y = submission)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_y_datetime(
    date_labels = "%H:%M", 
    limits = c(as.POSIXct("00:00:01", format="%H:%M:%S"), 
               as.POSIXct("23:59:59", format="%H:%M:%S")))
```

which plots:

[image]

However, the redundant `00:00` labels on y-axis is confusing.

How do I then plot an appropriate `day` vs. `submission` scatterplot while using y-axis as a 24 hrs clock?

Comment: Can you just remove this line? `mutate(submission = submission + lubridate::days(day - min(day)))`

Comment: Done. [Quinten's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74581068/7789963) helps with the original as well the edited question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could extract the hour minute second from your submission using `hms` from `hms` and use `scale_y_time` to make the y axis time like this:

```r
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
submits %>%
  mutate(submission = as.POSIXct(submission, format = "%H:%M:%S")) %>%
  mutate(submission = submission + lubridate::days(day - min(day))) %>%
  mutate(submission_time = hms::hms(second(submission),minute(submission),hour(submission))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x= day, y = submission_time)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_y_time()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

To answer [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7789963/medium-dimensional) and the updated question:

```
library(scales)
submits %>%
  mutate(submission = as.POSIXct(submission, format = "%H:%M:%S")) %>%
  mutate(submission_time = hms::hms(second(submission),minute(submission),hour(submission))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x= day, y = submission_time)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_y_time(breaks = scales::date_breaks("1 hours"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I have been unable to find any relevant argument of `scale_y_time` or use `scale_y_datetime` (instead of `scale_y_time`) to increase the resolution (more ticks) of y-axis while using hour-min labelling format. Could you suggest any method to handle that?

Comment: hi @medium-dimensional, if you want to add more ticks hourly for example, you could add `breaks = date_breaks('1 hour')` with `library(scales)`.